# Button position in kivy gridlayout

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to move this button to top-right but no matters what I do I just can't move it. It is **always** in the bottom-left and never leaves this position.

This is my .py:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # coding=UTF-8

    import kivy
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    Builder.load_file('listadex.kv')

    class TestS(GridLayout):
        def bt1(self):
            print 'Olar galera'        #layout.add_widget(bt1.Button(text='TestS'))

    class SegundaTela(App):
        def build(self):
    #layout = GridLayout(cols=2, row_force_default=False, row_default_height=10)
    #layout.add_widget(bt1.Button(text='TestS'))
    #layout.add_widget(bt2.Button(text='TestA'))
    #layout.add_widget(bt3.Button(text='TestD'))
    #layout.add_widget(bt4.Button(text='TestMC'))
    #return layout
    CF = TestS()
    return CF

    SegundaTela().run()
```

And this is my .kv

```
    <TestS>:
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 1
            padding: 3
            spacing: 3

            Button:
                text: 'botao1'
                on_press: root.bt1()
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.15}
```

Comment: where do you want to put the button?

Comment: its going to be at the top-ritgh of the screem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using relative layout. for example

```
RelativeLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'botao1'
        on_press: root.bt1()
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

change `center_x` and `center_y` till they meet your needs.

Comment: It's not working, this button covers all screem, I want to add more 3 buttons...
2 on the top and 2 on the bot

Comment: use `size_hint: None, None` and then define the size using `size: 400, 400` or any size you want

Comment: This works, Thank you very much, finally worked well =D